# Android client consumes API returns bad request

Tags: android, django, rest, retrofit

I am currently learning django and android. I created a REST API for my backend. The endpoints are working since I can GET/POST with Postman, Insomnia, and httpie. However, if I try it with my android app it gives the response 'Bad Request'. I've been working on it for many hours now. Could someone explain to me why is this happening?

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFF1j.jpg
![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzzth.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was using a lightweight server by django to run my api. Found out about gunicorn.